# Bind a controller function to a ui-router ui-href

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, passport.js

I'm new to angular so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I'm using ui-router for the states and links and passport for the user authentication. I have no problem creating a new user and signing in, but I want to create a link so the user can signout.

Is there any way to bind a function from my controller to a ui-href link?
For example:

**State routes**

```
    .state('usersignout', {
      url: '/users/signout',
      templateUrl: '/views/users/usuarios-signout.html',
      controller: 'UsersSignController',
      controllerAs: 'signCtrl'
    });
```

**Controller**

```
  .controller('UsersSignController', ['$http', '$state', 'Authentication',
    function($http, $state, Authentication) {
      this.logoutUser = function() {
        $http({
            // call my endpoint to do a passport's logout
            method: "GET",
            url: "/api/users/signout"
          })
          .then((response) => {
              //successCallback
              Authentication.setUser(null);
              $state.go('home');
            },
            (response) => {
              //errorCallback
              $state.go('error', {
                errorDetails: response
              });
            });
      };
    }
  ])
```

**HTML** (this isn't working, it's not binding the controller tied to usersignout)

```
  <a ui-sref="usersignout" ng-click="signCtrl.logoutUser()">Close Session</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply omit function declaration in controller

```
.controller('UsersSignController', ['$http', '$state', 'Authentication',
    function ($http, $state, Authentication) {
        $http({
            // call my endpoint to do a passport's logout
            method: "GET",
            url:    "/api/users/signout"
        }).then((response) => {
                //successCallback
                Authentication.setUser(null);
                $state.go('home');
            },
            (response) => {
                //errorCallback
                $state.go('error', {
                    errorDetails: response
                });
            });
    }
]);
```

Logout request will be invoked immediately after controller instance is initialized. You should also move http call to some service i.e.

```
.service('SomeService', function ($http, Authentication) {
    this.logout = function () {
        return $http.get("/api/users/signout")
            .then(() => {
                Authentication.setUser(null);
            })
    }
})
```

In that case controller should be look like:

```
.controller('UsersSignController', ['$state', 'SomeService',
    function ($state, SomeService) {
        SomeService.logout
            .then(() => {
                    $state.go('home');
                },
                (response) => {
                    //errorCallback
                    $state.go('error', {
                        errorDetails: response
                    });
                });
    }
])
```

Comment: Yes, I can move the http call to the Authentication service, but my problem is that I don't know how to call the controller's function. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Look at my first example I've removed this.logoutUser = function() { declaration. In that case logout logic will be invoked after you entered 'usersignout' state and you can remove 'ng-click="signCtrl.logoutUser()"' from your html. You won't be able to invoke controller function from this link, because when you click on this link you are not in 'usersignout' state.

Comment: Oh, I see, I'll give it a try later, Thanks